# DataGrid with Empty DataTable to allow user input C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have an application that has multiple tabs each containing a Datagrid that contains data from my database.  I have a save button that writes all the datagrids into a .csv file.  I want to create an additional tab that contains an empty datagrid so the user can type information so it can be output the same way.

Is there a way to bind a datagrid to an empty data table?  Or is there a better solution that will allow the user to dynamically enter variable amounts of information (somtimes one row, somtimes 10)

C#

```
DataTable dt_Call_Drivers = new DataTable();
Call_Drivers_DataGrid.ItemsSource = dt_Call_Drivers.DefaultView;
```

XAML

```
                        <DataGrid x:Name="Call_Drivers_DataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" CanUserAddRows="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                            <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridColumnHeader}">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                </Style>
                            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Case"  Width ="90" Binding="{Binding Case}">
                                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                        <Style>
                                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                        </Style>
                                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                </DataGridTextColumn>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just bind datagrid to ObservableCollection, define your type. And Set CanUserAddRows = true. That's all.

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding SimpleCollection}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding A}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding B}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding C}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>


    public class SimpleClass
    {
        public string A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
        public string C { get; set; }
    }

private ObservableCollection<SimpleClass> _simpleCollection;
public ObservableCollection<SimpleClass> SimpleCollection
{

get { return _simpleCollection ?? (_simpleCollection = new ObservableCollection<SimpleClass>());     }

set { _simpleCollection = value; }
}
```